# add 100 pixels height when adding rectangles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

My canvas has no height and i want to keep it like that. Static. Whenever i add a rectangle i would like to increase the height of the canvas with 100 pixels for example.

https://jsfiddle.net/5qybcp84

Whenever i add a rectangle now its just not shown as you can see in the fiddle.

I have tried using  `$("#NodeList").width('200').height($("#NodeList").height()+100);`

But it just increases the whole Canvas including the rectangles.

Comment: ```$("#NodeList").attr("height", $("#NodeList").height() + 100);``` Seems to increase the height of your canvas. But for some reason the rectangles disappear. This is not a solution, but hopefully will get you in the right direction.

Comment: `$('#NodeList').height($('#NodeList').height()+100);` is increasing the height of the canvas.

Comment: The thing is, i don't want it to increase when i click it. I want it to increase when i add more RECTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know canvas width/height was not meant to be changed when something is already drawn on it ( not unless for good reasons ).

In your example you already know in advance how many rectangles will be drawn on your canvas. Just set your canvas to the height before drawing on it.

If you absolutely want to keep the height of the canvas dynamic, then you'll need to clear the canvas and re-draw all your previous rectangles everytime you change your canvas height like so:

```
var canvas = $('#NodeList').get(0);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.height = 200;

var rects = [
    [20, 20, 150, 100],
    [20, 140, 150, 100],
    [20, 260, 150, 100]
];
for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    canvas.height = canvas.height + 100;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //here we redraw previous rectangles
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        ctx.fillRect(rects[j][0],
        rects[j][1],
        rects[j][2],
        rects[j][3]);
    }
    ctx.fillRect(rects[i][0],
    rects[i][1],
    rects[i][2],
    rects[i][3]);

}

$('#NodeList').click(function (e) {
    var x = e.offsetX,
        y = e.offsetY;

    for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
        if (x > rects[i][0] && x < rects[i][0] + rects[i][2] && y > rects[i][1] && y < rects[i][1] + rects[i][3]) {
            alert('Rectangle ' + i + ' clicked');
        }
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8g48bhu/)